# Bash curly expansion with space in the string

Tags: bash, scripting

I would like to use curly expansion to save some typing.

My desire expansion is:

```
-e uncore_imc0/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc1/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc2/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc3/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc4/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc5/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc6/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc7/cas_count_read/
```

I've tried:

```
-e uncore_imc{0..7}/cas_count_read/
```

but this only expand to (with -e only in the beginning)

```
-e uncore_imc0/cas_count_read/ uncore_imc1/cas_count_read/ uncore_imc2/cas_count_read/ uncore_imc3/cas_count_read/ uncore_imc4/cas_count_read/ uncore_imc5/cas_count_read/ uncore_imc6/cas_count_read/ uncore_imc7/cas_count_read/
```

If I tried:

```
{-e, uncore_imc{0..7}/cas_count_read/}
```

or

```
"-e uncore_imc{0..7}/cas_count_read/"
```

Neither would expand.

Comment: try  `"-e uncore_imc"{0..7}/cas_count_read/`

Comment: @123 That results in `-e uncore_imc0/cas_count_read` being a single word passed to the command as an argument, rather than two separate arguments `-e` and `uncore_imc0/cas_count_read`.

Comment: @123, your solution actually works for me. Looks like as long as the strings (with/without quotes) are concatenated without space, it will expand the whole thing, that's nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf`:

```
printf -- '-e uncore_imc%d/cas_count_read/ ' {0..7}; echo

-e uncore_imc0/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc1/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc2/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc3/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc4/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc5/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc6/cas_count_read/ -e uncore_imc7/cas_count_read/
```

You can also store this expansion in a variable like this:

```
printf -v arg -- '-e uncore_imc%d/cas_count_read/ ' {0..7}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is really for a script, don't use brace expansion. You only have to write the code once, so readability should be a higher priority. Create an array instead:

```
opts=()
for((i=0; i < 8; i++)); do
  opts+=(-e "uncore_imc$i/cas_count_read/")
done

someCommand "${opts[@]}"
```